# C# How to post data with multiple POST requests through Facebook API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, desktop-application

I've been trying to post a message along with a link, I can send one POST request, but I am not sure how would one send two.

Here's my code:

```
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com");

            string message = "hello";
            string link = "www.facebook.com"

            var payload = GetPayload(new {message});

            HttpResponseMessage response2 = client.PostAsync($"me/feed?access_token={TextBox1.Text}", payload).Result;

        }
    }

    private static StringContent GetPayload(object data)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        return new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    }
```

I am not sure how can I include the link too along with the message.

Comment: you need to create message which includes link it in. `string message = "hello www.facebook.com"` and then pass it to GetPayLoad method.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Maybe not... check out [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_post_links) which says to post the link as JSON with a "message" and "link" elements, just like in the OP's example.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the specifics of the Fb APIs. As per the article you shared the OP needs to do `var data = {message, link};` and then send it to `GetPayload` method.

Comment: Just because you want to specify a message and a link, doesn’t need you need to make two POST requests ... two such requests would create two individual post objects, and that’s clearly not what you want. But don’t expect this to work until you manage to specify a proper absolute URL - `www.facebook.com` isn’t one.

Comment: Thanks everyone var data = {message, link} worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al-right it turns out that the variable link should be passed as such:

```
var data = {message, link}
```

Thanks to chetan.